# How can I remove an eventListener in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-listener

I can't remove `eventListener`, not even with `React.useCallback`. So, what do I do now?

Here's my code, at the start of my component's class:

```js
const noCursorEventListener = React.useCallback((e) => {
    console.log('ncel');
    let lista = document.getElementsByClassName('lista');
    if (lista && lista[0]) lista[0].classList.remove('nocursor');
}, []);

window.addEventListener('mousemove', noCursorEventListener);
```

The useEffect I use to remove it:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', noCursorEventListener);
        window.onmousemove = null;
        console.log('remove el');
    }
});
```

I saw `remove el` correctly, but after that and after page changes, I still got a `ncel` message. How can I fix it?

That `window.onmousemove = null` shouldn't be necessary. It was a test that failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Don't do (non-hook) side-effects in render. :-) For lurkers, if you're just looking for how to properly add the event listener using DOM methods (in the rare cases where that's appropriate), see **The Standard Way** below.

But for those interested in why the OP's code didn't work:

### Why That Didn't Work

What you have will work for the *first* render, but not subsequent ones. *(If you're using React's `StrictMode`, it may have been rendering twice at the outset.)* You can see why if we log a message at each stage of what's happening (I've changed `mousemove` to `click` because it doesn't matter and it avoid cluttering the log):

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const noCursorEventListener = React.useCallback((e) => {
        console.log("event listener called!");
    }, []);

    console.log("Adding event listener");
    window.addEventListener("click", noCursorEventListener);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            console.log("Removing event listener");
            window.removeEventListener("click", noCursorEventListener);
        };
    });

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const increment = (event) => {
        setCounter(c => c + 1);
        event.stopPropagation();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {counter} <input type="button" value="+" onClick={() => setCounter((c) => c + 1)} />
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

If you run that, you'll see `Adding event listener` because the render adds the event listener. And if you click somewhere other than the button, you'll see `event listener called!`. But if you click the button to cause a second render, you'll see this sequence:

```
Adding event listener
Removing event listener
```

**Note the order**. It re-adds the event listener (which doesn't do anything, because you can't add the same event listener function for the same event to the same element more than once), and then after the render the `useEffect` cleanup for the *previous* render runs, removing the event listener. This is implicit in the way [`useEffect` cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect) works, but it can seem a bit surprising.

Amusingly, if you *weren't* memoizing the event listener, it would work because when adding, it would add a second event listener briefly, and then the first would be removed by the `useEffect` cleanup.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const noCursorEventListener = /*React.useCallback(*/(e) => {
        console.log("event listener called!");
    }/*, [])*/;

    console.log("Adding event listener");
    window.addEventListener("click", noCursorEventListener);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            console.log("Removing event listener");
            window.removeEventListener("click", noCursorEventListener);
        };
    });

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const increment = (event) => {
        setCounter(c => c + 1);
        event.stopPropagation();
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {counter} <input type="button" value="+" onClick={() => setCounter((c) => c + 1)} />
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

But **don't do that**. Other than calls to hooks, your `render` function should be pure (it shouldn't have meaningful side-effects). Adding an event listener is a meaningful side-effect.

Side effects are the whole point of `useEffect` ([more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)). So let's do it the standard way, by hooking up the listener in a `useEffect` callback and removing that same handler when the cleanup for that effect is done. (That also means we don't create a new listener function every time that we throw away.)

### The Standard Way

Here's the standard way to add an event listener on mount and remove it on unmount, for those relatively rare use cases where doing this with the DOM directly is appropriate:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const noCursorEventListener = (e) => {
        let lista = document.getElementsByClassName("lista");
        if (lista && lista[0]) lista[0].classList.remove("nocursor");
    };

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", noCursorEventListener);
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("mousemove", noCursorEventListener);
    };
}, []); // <== Empty dependencies array = only run effect on mount
```

(There's also a separate issue: [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) is a *performance optimization*, not a semantic guarantee. `useCallback` is a wrapper around [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo), which has this disclaimer *(their emphasis)*: *"**You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee.**"* But your code was relying on it as a semantic guarantee.)

Comment: Worked as charm. Thanks. I'm still getting used to React's frills :D

Comment: While that's surely the better way to do it, I'm wondering exactly why the original code wouldn't. The memoized function is a `const`. It shouldn't get garbage collected or recalculated until there's another render, so the function the cleanup callback references should always be the one that was just added at the beginning of the last render. Any ideas?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Amusingly, it's the stability that's the problem (well, that and performing a non-hook side-effect during render). The second render runs before the first render's clleanup happens. Since the listener is stable, the second call to `addEventListener` doesn't do anything, but the cleanup successfully removes it. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation. It was really useful. I wish I could upvote again :D